# Limiting GIF animation rate to its frame delay in JME3

Tags: java, animation, jmonkeyengine

I've figured out how to render a GIF image using [this library](https://github.com/rtyley/animated-gif-lib-for-java) as follows:

```
@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    if (bgFrameIndex > 0) {
        guiNode.detachAllChildren();
    }

    guiNode.attachChild(bgNodes.get(bgFrameIndex));

    if (bgFrameIndex < bgDecoder.getFrameCount() - 1) {
        ++bgFrameIndex;
    } else {
        bgFrameIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

where `bgDecoder` is a `GifDecoder`, `bgNodes` is an `ArrayList` of nodes that contain the GIF's frames, and `bgFrameIndex` is the current frame index to render. By default, the `tpf` (ticks per frame) variable is at around 0.01 seconds, when I want to limit it to the frame delay of the current frame without changing the FPS of the entire game. What's the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

My new code from the answer of @1000ml (I also fixed frame removal):

```
private float bgFrameDelay = bgDecoder.getFrameCount() > 0 ? bgDecoder.getDelay(bgFrameIndex) : 0;

@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) { // ticks per frame
     bgFrameDelay -= tpf;

     if (bgFrameDelay < 0F) {
         bgFrameDelay = bgDecoder.getDelay(bgFrameIndex) / 1000F;

         if (bgFrameIndex > 0) {
             bgNodes.get(bgFrameIndex - 1).removeFromParent();
         }

         guiNode.attachChild(bgNodes.get(bgFrameIndex));

         if (bgFrameIndex < bgDecoder.getFrameCount() - 1) {
             ++bgFrameIndex;
         } else {
             bgFrameIndex = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `Thread.sleep()` call to the `simpleUpdate()` method will throttle the whole jme thread. This will be very noticable when you add more elements to your application.

Here's a way to skip calls to `simpleUpdate()` until the desired delay is reached:

```
private float t = bgDecoder.getDelay(0);

public simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    t -= tpf;
    if(t > 0f) {
        return;
    }
    t = bgDecoder.getDelay(bgFrameIndex) / 1000f;

    // Your stuff goes here
}
```

You might have to adjust the frame index, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: The only problem is leaving your `t` variable outside the loop. The delay between frames can vary, and the way your code is now has the delay for the first frame used for all frames. I'd also test for our one true case and have the default return option do the work for me, like with `if (t < 0F) { // do my stuff }`

Comment: You might have to adjust the frame index, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using `Thread.sleep(bgDecoder.getDelay(bgFrameIndex));` and everything works perfectly! I'd love to hear any better alternatives.